# Cucumber .feature not working in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, automation, cucumber

I m trying to get started with cucumber but i can't seem to figure out why the *.feature file isn't recognised.

This is what I did till this point :

Pom file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

</project>
```

Then I made a package called features under test\java, in this package when i make the *.feature file, it comes up with a "?" next to it and it dosen't open, this should be a cucumber file right?

I have compiled the whole thing, it worked with no errors

Comment: Do you have "Cucumber" plugin installed/enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a really recent version of Cucumber (thnx!) and sometimes the IDE plugins take a while to catch up:
1. Try to upgrade your IDE and the plugin.
2. Search YouTrack for known issues related to the Cucumber plugin (and please upvote them!) or create one if it doesn't already exists.
3. Downgrade to a slightly older version of Cucumber that is working with your IDE.